# Webrick server not starting in Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm running the following:

- Windows 8 64-bit
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.12

When I try and start webrick i get the following output:

[image]

And yeah.. not starting up. Very strange. I'm very new to rails, so this could be a total n00b mistake. Thanks for a push in the right direction!

Comment: Ahhhh.. Told you guys it's a total noob mistake! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are not in your app path, assume that your app is in `C:\Path\to\rails\app`, first tell your console that should be in this path: `cd C:\Path\to\rails\app`. And then try using `rails s`

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you are in you Users\Dean folder, try starting `rails s` from your application root

Answer (score 2):

You must be in the right folder before starting the server.

```
cd appfolder
rails s
```

The same if you want to open the rails console

```
cd appfolder
rails c
```

However, to start the ruby console you don't need to be in the right folder, just:

```
irb
```